# How can I get a notification when Android AudioTrack underbuffers?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a callback or something if an AudioTrack object underbuffers, so that I can pause the playback until it refills. I'm guessing this would be useful to other people besides myself!

The only approach I could think of is to call Systemclock.elapsedRealtime() after every time I write a buffer and compare it to the number of milliseconds I've written to the AudioTrack, which I thought would give me the amount remaining in the buffer. But the measured time difference (shown in the log) either gradually increases or decreases as time goes on, rather than holding constant as it should. Can anyone see why?

Here's what I have. First to initialize:

```
msWritten = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Then to write a buffer:

```
track.write(samples, 0, length);

// convert stereo samples to ms
msWritten += length/88.2;

if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() > msWritten) {
    Log.e("UNDERRUN", String.valueOf(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-msWritten));
} else {
    Log.e("GOOD", String.valueOf(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-msWritten));
}
```